# Deploying Angular2 quickstar project

Tags: javascript, angular

I have cloned the Angular2 quickstart repo and build a simple app.  I want to publish it to the web now.  It runs locally but it references files directly inside the node_modules directory.

Is there a standard build process I can run that will copy all needed files to the output directory?  Or do I have to create this myself from scratch with a task runner or something?

Answer (score 1):

This is my first time to answer a question so bear with me if I didnt do it correctly.

If "bundling all angular 2 ts/js and other dependencies (core.js, rxjs, zone.js) into one js and create a script tag on index.html to reference the bundled js" close to the standard build process you mentioned and you want,  my answer is yes, you probably need to npm install some other tools to do it.

Since the angular 2 quickstart is using systemjs to do ES module loading, the tool you can use is called "systemjs builder" https://github.com/systemjs/builder which helps you to do bundling (based on systemjs.config.js) and yes, you can use a task tunner (grunt or gulp) with systemjs builder plugins (gulp-systemjs-builder or grunt-systemjs-builder) to create a task to "build".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter
And using `npm run build:dev` or `npm run build:prod`
It will build a `dist` folder and that's all you need.